# Is it possible to combine Knockout Bindings, which use the same value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've noticed there are a few places where I want to use the `if` and `visible` binding.

I tend to want to use the `if` so that it doesn't perform any actions that may occur in any child nodes that have their own data-bindings. And I want to use `visible` as using `if` doesn't hide the root element, just the inner elements, meaning that it can cause layout issues.

Anyway, description aside, could I have something that does this...

```
<div class="exampleDiv" data-bind="visible: active(), if: active()">
```

But like this?

```
<div class="exampleDiv" data-bind="ifvisible: active()">
```

Comment: I'm confused. The `if` binding's features is a superset of `visible`, non? Put in another way, visibility is *implied* by the `if` binding? Can you add code / a repro for a scenario where this would matter, i.e. where having an `ifvisible` binding would matter?

Comment: The problem I had was that while using `if` did indeed mean that the inner elements were not generated, I still had the root element. In my case, this resulted in a `<ul...>` without any `<li...>`s. Meaning that I didn't see any elements, but it still took up some space in my bar. Visibility on the other hand seemed to make it completely invisible, child elements existing or not.

Comment: Yes, seeing @RoyJ's answers and your accept-mark next to it things now make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* [write a custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) to "wrap" existing bindings. In the `init` section, you would call the `init` methods of the bindings you're wrapping, and in the `update` section, their updates.

You could also get the effect you want by [using the `if` binding in a virtual element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element) around the div you wanted to hide:

```
<!-- ko if: active() -->
  <div class="exampleDiv">...</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```